# Register classes with primitive dependencies in ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, .net-core

I got baffled on how can i resolve connection string dependency on `UserRepo` once it is injected on an mvc controller by ASP NET Core's DI? Note that my repo is targeting NET 4.6. and uses either sql db with dapper orm. Tips and advice will do.

Heres the code.

Interface to be depended

```
public interface IUserRepo
{
  List<User> GetAll();
}
```

Concrete class that will be injected to mvc controller and has its own dependency

```
public class UserRepo: IUserRepo
{
   private string connectionString = "";

   //Depends on a connectionstring
   public UserRepo(string connectionString)
   {
      this.connectionString  = connectionString;
   }

   public  List<User> GetAll()
   {
      //create an sqlconnection using provided  connectionstring
      //return list from db...
   }
}
```

on ASP MVC CORE's startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
   services.AddMvc();
   //inject UserRepo , how to resolve UserRepo's dependency?
   services.AddScoped<IUserRepo, UserRepo>();
}
```

Comment: why don't you use Configuration to resolving connection string from AppSetting ? https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `AddScoped` overload that accepts a delegate:

```
services.AddScoped<IAccountRepo>(c => new AccountRepo("constr"));
```

Comment: I want to use it with AddHostedService which does not have an overload that accepts a delegate. Any suggestions here?
The Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  suggests to use Configuration pattern.

Answer (score 0):

### I suggest you using configuration based on ASP.NET Core documentation

If you have configuration setting (`appsettings.json`) like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1-26e8893e-d7c0-4fc6-8aab-29b59971d622;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
}
```

And your Startup.cs:

```
private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
    _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional:false, reloadOnChange:true)
        .Build(); 
}


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(provider => _configuration);
    ...
}
```

Then you can resolve it on the UserRepo easily:

```
public class UserRepo: IUserRepo
{
   private readonly string connectionString;

   public UserRepo(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      this.connectionString  = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");;
   }

   public  List<User> GetAll()
   {
      //create an sqlconnection using provided  connectionstring
      //return list from db...
   }
}
```

Comment: I vote against this, because you couple the `UserRepo` to the ASP.NET `IConfiguration` abstraction, move [unnecessary logic into your constructor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), and cause invalid configurations to only popup at runtime, instead directly when the application is started.

Comment: @Steven tnx Steven. but the IConfiguration is not part of ASP.NET it's in "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" package, by the way it was just a sample and IOptions<TOptions> could be used...

Comment: The use of `IOptions<T>` in your services *is even worse* as I explained in detail [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/143#issuecomment-155029876).